# python: Delete consecutively repeated words in sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have the following sentence:

```
s = "Et puis j'obtiens : [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] Donc, ça veut dire que la suite de nombres réels"
```

As you can see [voir écran] appears to often. I just want to have it appear ones.

I tried (similar to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34039/regex-to-remove-repeating-words-in-a-sentence) :

```
from itertools import groupby


no_dupes = ([k for k, v in groupby(sent_clean.split())])


# Put the list back together into a sentence
groupby_output = ' '.join(no_dupes)
print('No duplicates:', groupby_output)
```

**...but it did not work.**

Comment: How would you define a repeated string? Because here it is not just one word, but two. Is it always two or max two? Is it always between brackets?

Comment: @Roelant Very true. Yes, it is between two brackets.

Comment: Cant you use replace builtin on the list?

Comment: It does not work because the `split()` method also split the '[voir écran]' expressions, making duplicates not consecutives...

Comment: Question: do you want to remove any duplicates, or only the '[voir écran]' ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a slightly more complicated regex to identify repeating phrases in brackets:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'(\[[^\]]*\])(?:\s*\1)+')

print(pat.sub(r'\1', s))
# Et puis j'obtiens : [voir écran] Donc, ça veut dire que la suite de nombres réels
```

`(\[[^\]]*\])` captures any number of non `]` characters between two brackets, and `(?:\s*\1)+` looks for repetitions of that group next to it.  We then replace those multiple occurrences of the group with a single occurence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Using `split()` will also split `'[voir ecran]'` -you can however split manually:

O(n) solution traversing your string one time:

```
# uses line continuation \
s =  "Et puis j'obtiens : [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran]" \
    "[voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran]" \
    "[voir écran] [voir écran] [voir écran] Donc, ça veut" \
    "dire que la suite de nombres réels"

seen = set()
result = []
tmp = []
for c in s:
    if tmp and c == "]":
        tmp.append(c)
        tmp = ''.join(tmp)
        if tmp not in seen:
            result.append(tmp)
            seen.add(tmp)
        tmp = []
    elif tmp:
        tmp.append(c)
    elif not tmp and c == "[":
        tmp.append(c)
    else:
        result.append(c)

if tmp and tmp not in seen:
    result.append(tmp)
    seen.add(tmp)
    tmp = []

s_after = ''.join(result)
print(s_after)
```

Output:

```
Et puis j'obtiens : [voir écran]          Donc, ça veut dire que la suite de nombres réels
```

The multiple spaces are *not* removed from the result - you would need to do this afterwards.

---

You traverse the string - add each character to a list until you hit `[`. You then collect all characters into `tmp` until you hit `]`. You `join` it, and check your `seen` set if you already added it - if so do nothing and reset `tmp` - else add it and reset `tmp`. If you later encounter the same `[...]` it will not be added.

Continue until end - if `tmp` filled, add it. (might be a `'[some rest text no bracked'` in it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !